# Is there a tag for "copy this photo look"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm interested in answering questions that relate to "how do I achieve this effect?", but I don't see a tag for that type of question.  Is there one?

Answer (score 7):

I think the closest we have is [reverse-engineering](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-engineering). Tag summary is:

> Analysis of an image to determine setup and techniques that could be used to achieve certain properties of the image.

Downsides:

- not obvious to non-geeks
- has a hardware implication (despite the tag description)

Just [effect](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect) is pretty common in practice, even though that's kind of terrible.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of the questions we get - unfortunately many of them too broad & are soon closed - tend to start with the assumption that everything is a 'filter' as in a Snapchat/Instagram filter.

[filter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter)[filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) or [software-filter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-filter)

This one **is** actually looking for equivalents to Snapchat filters - [How can I recreate Snapchat's built-in filter effects?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/102238/how-can-i-recreate-snapchats-built-in-filter-effects)

As [mattdm](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm) has already mentioned, these would tend to be back-tagged with [effect](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effect) or [reverse-engineering](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-engineering)

Maybe we should have a [whats-this-effect](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whats-this-effect) tag, perhaps linked back to [reverse-engineering](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-engineering)?
There's also [post-processing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-processing) (which feels odd to me, as I've always known it as *post-production* rather than processing.)

Personally, I like these types of challenge, if the question or examples are sufficiently well-honed to know precisely what 'effect' is being asked about.

Link to [How should we handle the "what (Instagram) filter is makes this photo" type questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5433/57929) for the current state of play on some of these questions.

Comment: Interesting suggestion re: 'whats-this-effect' tag. While I admit that I kinda like it (or something like it), I think we should be careful about exactly what kind of questions we're interested in encouraging (to the point of giving them their own tag category). Are we interested in attracting, encouraging, or curating "What's this effect, i.e., what filter do I use in [App X] to look like [celebrity Y]?" Or are we interested more in questions like "What adjustments in [App A] can I use to simulate this [effect B]?" The latter seem like interesting RE challenges. But the former... meh.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply have a `photo-style` tag? Or simply `style`?

Comment: We already _do_ have [tag:style], and it's kind of a mess.

Comment: Eesh, yeah....it is a mess...

Comment: "Photo Style" is also very close to "Picture Style", a specific terminology used by Canon.