# Should we elect an additional mod specifically to help with the contest?

Tags: discussion, support, election, contest, moderators

In the [discussion on refreshing the photo contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5897/1943), current mod @MikeW says:

> Available mods. There are periods when one or two mods don't visit for a week or more. I try to keep the "weekly" contest weekly, but often 10-14 days go by before I remember to do it. AJ and I can try to be more diligent about it, but that's my main concern, is the need to update stuff in a timely manner. The rolling nature of the existing contest makes it not super important that mods action things regularly. The new contest would require us to be on top of things a bit more. Shouldn't be a big problem however.

Should we elect a new mod with helping to maintain the contest weekly *specifically* as a responsibility? (They'd still be a regular mod and be able to help out in other ways too, and the other mods could cover the contest when necessary, but the primary focus would be on this.)

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to establish privileges to manage the contest that don't go full mod? I ask because helping with the contest is something I'd volunteer to do. Wearing the full mod hat on the other hand...and I'd guess there are additional people who may feel similarly.

Comment: Existing mods, any opinion?

Comment: Not really.  This site isn't that busy for the mods.  Happy to have another one though.

Comment: I'd echo what MikeW said.  Another mod wouldn't be horrible but also isn't super pressing I don't think.  JRista is still around, though things are mostly two mods at this point.  Outside the contest, I think a lot of that reason is because the site isn't really that demanding even on two active mods, but I know personally I suck at scheduled stuff.  My schedule is hectic enough I don't even know what day it is half the time, so I'm pretty useless when it comes to remembering to update the contest.

Comment: As soon as the moderator team indicate that there isn't sufficient coverage, that's an indication that the mod team is too small. There should be mods aplenty, with redundancy and depth, not a team that's able to cope.