# Stack Exchange employees: somebody do something about the contest

Tags: discussion, support, contest, moderators

We're at the point where low-quality entries which did not even follow the contest rules are being selected as winners. We had a proposal with some energy behind it, but a moderator shot it down without offering any viable alternatives.

[Contest is definitely dead. Now what?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/contest-is-definitely-dead-now-what) has almost no attention and some lackluster suggestions.

I'd love for some good suggestions to develop there, but in the meantime, for goodness' sakes, please at least stop the dead contest. I flagged for the post to be locked but that was denied, and, worse, my comment explaining the situation rolled back by the same moderator who killed the suggestion to do something active instead.

I would like someone with the power to do so to:

1. Take the current contest off of life support.
2. Elect some new moderators interested in positive activity to grow the site rather than just blocking and draining anyone's attempt to do anything

Answer (score 2):

The photo in question was posted 3 years ago. After a couple of weeks, it was pointed out that the size was wrong, so he swapped in a different photo. He didn't appear to do this  to bump the photo and attract more votes, which is the point of the rule. It happened shortly after submission.  3 years pass and that photo, which wasn't dealt with back then, rises to the top and I used my judgement to allow it to stand.  Looks like the size is still wrong, so that's my bad.

That's the only issue with submissions that I can recall in several years as moderator.  You make it sound like it's rampant.

As for changing the contest, there was very little consensus on the issue, so nothing has happened.  I'm all for it if we can iron out the issues.  But I do think the current one, imperfect as it is, adds to the site.

Comment: How many votes came in before the photo was swapped? The rules _specifically_ say that swapping the photo for something other than a minor change (like cropping) is disallowed.

Comment: As for consensus: there's barely more than two or three votes for _anything_ on meta these days, which is likely symptomatic of the larger problem. I think we have as much consensus as it's possible to get.

Comment: Anyway, that photo being selected is just the last straw here. That's not really my main complaint.

Comment: (Also, keep in mind that I _wrote_ that rule about swapping photos, so I definitely know its intent.)

Comment: And, Mike, I do appreciate the effort you've put into this over the years. But... no input on [what to do next](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/contest-is-definitely-dead-now-what)? You gave some feedback on [the one real proposal](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/proposal-rules-for-new-photo-contest-on-main-site/), which I appreciate, but then nothing later when AJ came and stomped on it, which apparently effectively ended the whole thing.

Comment: Not sure about how many votes, I don't think that's visible.

I was in Yellowstone for a few weeks when the "what to do next?" post was made. I never saw it.  Will go through it and reply.

Comment: Right, that's why switching isn't allowed. Even if it wasn't malicious, someone might have voted up the spider picture and not intended to vote up the disembodied eye that "won".

Comment: And also: when we started this, I expected the bar to win to continually get _higher_. That is, rather than needing 30 votes to win, you might need 40 or 50. That's not where we're at now. At this point, instead of really getting the cream of the crop, we're getting the middle "meh" ones that got some-teen votes over the last decade.

Comment: @mattdm It received no votes before the image was changed. All of the votes were for the eye image, none for the spider.

Comment: @Catija Again, ***that's not really my main complaint***. Kind of frustrating that that's the only thing anyone showed up to address.