# Contest Proposal: Replace image size requirement with a ratio limit

Tags: discussion

**Proposal:** Replace image size requirements with a ratio limit. For *example*, image ratio should not exceed 16:9.

**Rationale:** There is no need for a set limit on image dimensions because Imgur automatically generates thumbnails that can be used (by adding `m` to the image file name).

Also, image dimension limits may discourage participation. In [Contest is definitely dead. Now what?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6947/75526), [Ben](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/contest-is-definitely-dead-now-what?cb=1#comment12262_6947) commented:

> Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide." This is a pretty astonishing constraint in 2019. I was going to submit a photo, but frankly if this is the viewable size, it's almost pointless.

Answer (score 4):

The image URL needs to be a good size for page loading efficiently, but otherwise we can probably remove most constraints at this point.  When the contest started, it had to specifically fit a particular size box on the layout or the layout would render incorrectly.  That hasn't been true since the site redesign and the size constraints (other than load time related) are now unnecessary.

Comment: Imgur thumbnails (referred to by appending letters to the file name, such as `m`, `l`, and `t`) are of reduced resolution and should load as efficiently as any other image of similar resolution.