# Why is the photo contest in Meta and not in the Main?

Tags: discussion, contest, photographer

I think the photo contest is the most interesting thing on the site and should get even more importance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contest is definitely dead. Now what?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/contest-is-definitely-dead-now-what)